Modify ABP Framework default password policies
I would like to override the default ABP framework (v8.1) password policies . I have tried below but its not working as expected. Am I missing something ?
        context.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {

        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    });


Could you please check whether the settings are applied under in the side menu of the application -> Administration -> settings -> identityManagement
